# Use laravel 4 passwords with phalcon

Tags: php, hash, laravel-4, bcrypt, phalcon

I am trying to use my stored passwords from Laravel 4 in a fresh Phalcon Installation. I have no idea whether this is possible and tried it this way in the SessionController of the Phalcon sample-apllication INVO:

```
#$password = sha1($password);
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Can I use another Hash-Algorythm in phalcon, that fits to Laravel 4 Passwords, or can I convert the hashes somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use laravel hashses - all you need to do is to check how Laravel is creating and checking them.

Check [this code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php#L21) from `BCryptHasher::make()` and [this for validating](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php#L43).

The problem is that in Laravel this algorithm is a bit different. First is obtaining user from database then checking if password is the same with password_verify. While in INVO you first hash the given password and then you search for a user with given email and hash - if it finds anything then it can log user. Below should do the trick knowing the `$cost` value from Laravel settings (class defaults to 10).

```
$password = password_hash($value, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => $cost));
```

Edit: while above would be true for SHA1 & similar. The [INVO code](https://github.com/phalcon/invo/blob/master/app/controllers/SessionController.php#L84) should be changed to match the login algorithm in Laravel and BCrypt itself:

```php
$user = Users::findFirst(array("email = :email: AND active='Y'", 'bind' => array('email' => $email));
if ($user != false && password_verify($user->password, $this->request->getPost('password'))) {
   // login user
}
```

Laravel is using BCrypt for a reason - it is generally very good choice for hashing so you should stick to it.

Anyway you could write a password migration which will do upon each user successful login:

1. validate user password using old hashing algorithm
2. checks if User has migrated it's password (ie by checking some database field - or separated table)
3. hash given password with new algorithm
4. store new hash and update user table (with information that hash has been changed)

Which is rather complicated and should be needed only when migrating to "better" algorithm.

Comment: still no success. I know the cost, it is 10, but can't log in. perhaps I need to use the laravel 'secret'? is it used as salt?(and how can this function compare the hash in the database with its own when it creates another hash every time)(?)

Comment: So my fault - I've forgot about that. In that case you must do it like in Laravel - first get the user if exists - check the password.